# Deleting rows from table in vue.js not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<b-row>
                    <b-form-group class="col-md-12" id="input-group-12">
                      <h2 class="h2">Přidání příloh</h2>
                      <a
                        href="#"
                        class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"
                        @click="addRow"
                      >
                      </a>
                      <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                          <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0">
                            <div class="row">
                              <tr
                                v-for="(row, index) in rows"
                                :key="index.toString()"
                                class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-block"
                              >
                                <td>
                                 <b-form-file
                                    v-model="row.id"
                                    accept=".pdf"
                                    placeholder="Vyberte PDF soubor"
                                    drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
                                  ></b-form-file>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <a
                                    @click="removeElement(index)"
                                    class="plus-minus-toggle"
                                  ></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>

                      <div></div>
                    </b-form-group>
                  </b-row>

export default {
  components: { Multiselect /*pdf*/ },
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()

      var elem = document.createElement('tr')
      console.log(elem)
      this.rows.push({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        file: {
          name: 'Vyberte přílohu'
        }
      })
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      console.log(index)
      /*   if (index >= 0) {

      }
      index + 1
      return false*/
      this.rows.splice(index, 1)
      index + 1
    },
    setFilename: function(event, row) {
      //var file
      /* if (event.target.files[0] !== 1) {
        this.$refs.index.innerText = 'Vyberte přílohu'
        return
      }
*/
      var file = event.target.files[0]
      row.file = file
    }
  }
}
```

**I have this code but it is not deleting properly when I have standart input type text the function removeElement is working properly.
I just don't know where the fault is
Any suggestions please ?
I did research on google but with no luck.
Can you please help me ?
I edited code now i have methods and also data.
**

Comment: Jakub, could you post your code exactly is as in the file? The 'removeElement' should be a method.

Comment: i edited post and added data and methods

Comment: What do you mean with "not working properly"? Does it sometimes work, but other times not? And what do you mean with when you have "standart input type text"? How does the text input relate to the table rows?

Comment: it is not deleting the proper row when i click delete button, when i am using input text it is working normally

Comment: Why are you using index.toString() on your :key binding?

Comment: because otherwise it si giving me error that is not string but number

Comment: here is comparing when i have input text and input type file to see exactly my problem in action:https://recordit.co/qnzRHp3Kyx https://recordit.co/auvwh8KbdV

Comment: Do not use the table index to indicate row keys. During the splice operation on the array, these indexes change, they are numbered from the beginning. If you delete the middle item, all others update their index -1.

Comment: what should I use then?

Comment: They are smarter here for me in this matter, but I could suggest you to add a counter similar to auto increment in databases. You increase the counter for each item you add and assign it to the item. You are deleting an item that has a given counter value (read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array).

Comment: i am new to vue how exactly can i change my example to make it work ? i dont understand it from the example you posted

Comment: i am using incrementing here in my function removeElement: index + 1

Comment: The `index + 1` expression is not saved. If you wrote `this.index += 1` it would be a change.

Comment: I am currently doing an example to insert into the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203758/discussion-between-gander-and-jakub-bocek).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example illustrating my suggestion

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  template: "#main",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
      items: [],
      index: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addRow(text) {
      this.items.push({
        text: text || this.text,
        index: this.index++,
        file: null
      });
    },
    removeRow(index) {
      this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.index !== index);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addRow("Foo");
    this.addRow("Bar");
    this.addRow("Fus");
    this.addRow("Ro");
    this.addRow("Dah");
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">Vue App</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="main">
  <div>
    <input v-model="text" />
    <button @click="addRow()">Add</button>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="`file-row-${item.index}`">
          <td>{{item.text}}</td>
          <td>{{item.index}}</td>
          <td><b-form-file v-model="item.file" accept=".pdf"></b-form-file></td>
          <td><button @click="removeRow(item.index)">x</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but i need add input file to table not just plain text

Comment: Here you are. File field added.

Comment: thank you so much but one more thing compiler si giving me error:Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives in tr

Comment: Add something like ```<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`file-row-${index}`">``` so your TR has a unique key. Though using index is usually a bad idea, so if your `item` object contains something unique use that instead like ```:key="`file-row-${item.id}`"``` if your item contains a unique id

Comment: @JakubBocek, If my answer has been helpful, accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Gander one more thing how do i reset this file inputs if i have this in form and want clear them out ?

Comment: @JakubBocek [Form File Input: Clearing the file selection](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-file/#clearing-the-file-selection). Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Gander yeah but it is in array so it is giving me error this.$refs.file-input.reset is not a function

Comment: @JakubBocek Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. There was no `$refs` in this question and I didn't use it myself so I don't even know how to deal with it. Why not put a **new question** with an example that doesn't work for you?